# Is there a way to make Banshee show current song playing in Empathy?

Tags: banshee, empathy

Is there a way to make Banshee show the current song playing in Empathy? I remember Rhythmbox had this functionality. But I don't even see an extra plugins option in Banshee. All I see is the Extensions in Preferences. Is there some way to achieve what I need? I am on 11.04 btw

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Among its many other [awesome features](http://www.webupd8.org/2010/03/banshee-telepathy-extension-allows-you.html), the **Telepathy extension for Banshee** (banshee-extension-telepathy) will let you do this.  To make it work:

1. Install 'Telepathy extension for Banshee' from the Ubuntu Software Center
2. In Banshee, go to Edit > Preferences > Extension (tab), and check the box next to "Telepathy" in the "Community Extensions" section.
3. A new section called "Contacts" should be added to the left side of Banshee.  Right click on it and select "Share Currently Playing"

Comment: Still no change in the IM status :(

Comment: Sorry my first answer was a bit vague.  I'm not at my Ubuntu computer, but I've updated the answer with better instructions that should work (I tested them on a virtual machine).